# How to update function so it responds to certain emails automatically

Tags: google-apps-script, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-pubsub

I have a script that, when I run it, will automatically respond to emails with the subject "For Review (TEST):" with an automated message. Basically, if the subject of the email contains a specific date, the script will look to see if there is a Bank Holiday within the last 7 days and if so, it will be included in the auto-response.

Right now, I have this on a timer to run every hour, but the ideal version of this is that it would run each time I get an email with the subject "For Review (TEST):". However, this doesn't seem to be an option when I go to set up the Trigger. Is this something Google does not allow?

**EDIT: I have pieced together the following script and have configured my GCC with the information below. This is my first GCC project and I am still wrapping my head around how it works. I have sent my self a test email, but nothing has happened. Do I have this configured correctly? From the handleEmailNotification function below, I should get an email anytime my inbox gets an email with the subject line "For Review (TEST):"**

MY SCRIPT

```
function setupGmailWatch() {

  const topicName = 'projects/PROJECTID/topics/TOPIC';
  const url = 'https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/me/watch';

  const options = {
    method: 'post',
    headers: {
      Authorization: 'Bearer ' + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()
    },
    contentType: 'application/json',
    muteHttpExceptions: true,
    payload: JSON.stringify({
      labelIds: ['INBOX'],
      topicName: topicName
    })
  };

  const response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
  Logger.log(response.getContentText());
};

function createWatchTrigger() {
  try {
    ScriptApp.newTrigger('setupGmailWatch')
      .timeBased()
      .everyWeeks(1)
      .create();

  } catch (e) {
    MailApp.sendEmail({
      to: Session.getActiveUser().getEmail(),
      subject: 'Failed to set up Gmail Watch trigger',
      body: 'An error occurred when trying to set up the Gmail Watch trigger: ' + e.message
    });
    
  }
};

function handleEmailNotification(message) {

  const data = Utilities.newBlob(Utilities.base64DecodeWebSafe(message.data)).getDataAsString();
  const emailData = JSON.parse(data);
  const historyId = emailData.historyId;

  const historyList = Gmail.Users.History.list('me', {startHistoryId: historyId, historyTypes: 'messageAdded'});
  const messages = historyList.history.map(function(history) {return history.messages;}).flat();

  messages.forEach(function(message) {
    const email = GmailApp.getMessageById(message.id);
    const subject = email.getSubject();

    // Check if the email subject is "For Review (TEST):"
    if (subject.includes("For Review (TEST):")) {
      MailApp.sendEmail({
      to: Session.getActiveUser().getEmail(),
      subject: 'YOU GOT AN EMAIL',
      body: 'You got an email'
    });
    }
  });
  
};

function doPost(e) {

  var message = JSON.parse(e.postData.contents).message;
  handleEmailNotification(message);
  return ContentService.createTextOutput();

};
```

MY PROJECT'S GCC SETTINGS
[image]

Comment: https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/push#getting_mailbox_updates

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I made a sample of the process, it is a little tricky, since you need to make sure you follow all the steps correctly. If one of them is missing, you will get an error message.

Here are the steps:

1. You will need to [create a project](https://developers.google.com/workspace/guides/create-project).
2. Setup and `OAuth consent screen`. Steps can be found [here](https://developers.google.com/workspace/guides/configure-oauth-consent).
3. [Link the GCP project](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/cloud-platform-projects#switch_to_a_different_standard) to your Apps script project. (if you do not have one, you will need to create it following the steps [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/projects#create-and-delete)).
4. [Enable the pub/sub API](https://developers.google.com/chat/api/guides/firewall/pub-sub#create_a_pubsub-enabled) in the project linked to the Apps script.
5. Create a `Topic` & `Subscription` as `pull` (i.e. initiated by your app) in the GCP project. You can do this by following the steps [here](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/publish-receive-messages-console), or you can click on `Guide me` in the same documentation for step-by-step guidance.
6. Add `gmail-api-push@system.gserviceaccount.com` as a `principal`, you can do this in the `IAM` page or inside the `topic` page.
7. Go back to the Apps Script project, and [enable](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/concepts/manifests#editing_a_manifest) `Show "appsscript.json" manifest file in editor` from the `Project settings`.
8. [Add the following scopes](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/concepts/scopes#setting_explicit_scopes) to the manifest.

```
  "oauthScopes": [
    "https://mail.google.com/",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/pubsub",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.metadata",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.external_request"
  ]
```

9. Add the `Gmail API` [advance services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced#enable_advanced_services) to the Apps Script project.
10. I personally created a filter in the `Gmail settings` to [automatically sort](https://support.google.com/a/users/answer/9282734?hl=en#zippy=%2Clearn-how:%7E:text=Automatically%20label%20and%20sort%20messages) all the emails with a specific subject to a label called `PubSub`.

Lastly, here is a sample code for `Pub/Sub` using labels.

```
function testWebhooks() {
  let email = 'user@domain.com';
  let data = request_body = {
    "labelIds": [
      'PubSub'
    ],
    "labelFilterBehavior": 'INCLUDE',
    "topicName": 'projects/project-111/topics/the_topic'
  };

  let watchResponse = Gmail.Users.watch(data,email)

  console.log(watchResponse);

}
```

*Note: All the hyperlinks will take you to the Google Documentation you need to follow to complete the steps and you can also us* [this article](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/push)

### Update:

As per Google  Documentation:

> Additionally, a successful watch call should cause a notification to immediately be sent to your Cloud Pub/Sub topic.

You will see the history inside of

If you want to receiving notifications inside the subscription that you created. Inside `Pub/Sub` > `Subscriptions` > `Select the subscription you created` > `Messages` tab > `Pull`.

If you want to receive email notification to your inbox, when your pub/sub subscription receives a message, then you will need to add a Pub/Sub trigger, you can use a `cloud function` for it. You can read more about it in [this documentation](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/calling/pubsub#console), or you can use `background functions` more information [here](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/writing/write-event-driven-functions#background-functions).

Comment: Just posting this comment to let everyone know I have been using these instructions and I'm extremely close to making it work. I am so extremely appreciative and grateful that you Giselle for taking the time to post this comment, and I believe soon I will be able to update the results. This is exactly what I needed. Update soon!

Comment: Hey there, I just posted an edit. Not sure how to get this to work